# why are Twig template variables with markup not being rendered?

Tags: 8, theming

In my template preprocess function I have a variable:

```
$test = "<p>this is a paragraph</p>";
```

and I pass it to my template:

```
$variables['test'] = $test;
```

and output it in twig:

```
{{test}}
```

but instead of getting a formatted paragraph, I'm getting the original output in plain text:

```
<p>this is a paragraph</p>
```

How do I get Drupal to render this as normal HTML?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because twig auto-escapes unsafe content and your content isn't marked as safe.

You can explicitly tell it that it is with `$test = Markup::create($test)`; but you should be *very* careful with that. If it contains any sort of user input, you might open yourself for XSS issues.

Better approaches are using a render array like ['#markup' => 'your text'] which by default will allow a certain amount of html tags but not all of them. You can also use an inline template as documented here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2311123.

Twig natively understands render arrays, so it doesn't matter for your template if you provide a render array or a string.

Comment: I found that by using the raw filter, I get the output I need, so: {{test|raw }} gives 'this is a paragraph' without the markup.

Comment: ok, so raw is unsafe and I don't understand how I should use the example documentation you provided

Comment: Ok, with the help of some #drupal IRC idlers I found this: https://www.drupal.org/node/2296163 which contains a few options for outputting markup in twig.

Comment: In my example, I retrieved $test from a db query, and the field data was stored with markup (basic html ckeditor field), so the #markup method was the most relevant for this use case.

Comment: @RominRonin, just seen this comment. If this is data stored in a formatted text field this is a completely different question. Then #markup is unsafe. You have to render it with processed_text. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/223967/how-do-i-output-html-from-a-text-long-field-in-twig

Answer (score 15):

These are two possibilities to wrap $test in a paragraph and pass it to the twig template:

```
$variables['test'] = [
  '#markup' => $test,
  '#prefix' => '<p>',
  '#suffix' => '</p>',
];

$variables['test'] = [
  '#type' => 'inline_template',
  '#template' => '<p>{{ text }}</p>',
  '#context' => [
    'text' => $test,
  ],
];
```

Comment: I was trying to create a render array in Twig to pass that to a sub-template via include. The Markup render array doesn't work, but the inline_template worked. Yea, seems like I need to pass the #allowed_tags too.