# How to safely render node body on a custom variable?

Tags: theming, 8

I created a custom template for my programmatically created block.

I defined a variable for the template called test

so in my render array I have

```
'#test' => $node->get('body')->value
```

Problem is when I print `{{ test }}` in my twig template, it literally prints the html rather than rendering it. Ex: `<p> My node body </p>`

I've also have tried:

```
'#test' => $node
```

Then on twig `{{ test.body.value }}`

but same result, the html does not get rendered.

The only way I found to make render is by doing `{{ test.body.value|raw }}` but **raw filter should never be used on user entered data**.

How can I make Drupal stop escaping the html safely?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Build a render element `processed_text` and set the text format from the body field, so that the right text filters are applied before you print the field with {{ body }}:

If you have the `node` in `#test` like in your second example:

```
'#test' => $node
```

then you can build the render element in twig:

```
{% set body = {
  '#type':   'processed_text',
  '#text':    test.body.value,
  '#format':  test.body.format,
} %}

{{ body }}
```

This is the preferred method, see the documentation of `check_markup()`:

> Note: this function should only be used when filtering text for use
>   elsewhere  than on a rendered HTML page. If this is part of a HTML
>   page, then a  renderable array with a #type 'processed_text' element
>   should be used instead  of this, because that will allow cacheability
>   metadata to be set and bubbled  up and attachments to be associated
>   (assets, placeholders, etc.). In other  words: if you are presenting
>   the filtered text in a HTML page, the only way  this will be presented
>   correctly, is by using the 'processed_text' element.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21filter%21filter.module/function/check_markup/8.2.x

---

Render element in php:

```
'#test' => [
  '#type' => 'processed_text',
  '#text' => $node->body->value,
  '#format' => $node->body->format,
],
```

and print in twig:

```
{{ test }}
```

Comment: Cool, I didn't know you could do stuff like this on twig. I'm gonna go with @Japan's answer just because it's a little more bullet proof since someone else is going to be doing the theming. I know I am splitting hairs here.

Comment: You can build the render element in php as well, but you really should use the render element, see the documentation.

Comment: `you really should use the render element` fantabulous, one slight problem, my actual scenario `#test` is an array of node objects (didn't mention this in the Q to keep it simple). Not sure how I am going to make the twig looping work with the **Render element in php** approach. Might not be possible.

Comment: Make test a multidimensional array, that's the solution.

Comment: Yes, put an array in #test with multiple `processed_text` render elements, all array keys that don't start with a '#' will be considered as render children, also the numbers of an indexed array. You don't need a loop, twig renders all render children it finds in {{ test }} automatically.

Comment: btw. you need to add cache tags from the nodes to the render array if you want that this gets invalidated when a node is modified, or create a view mode for the content type to output the body fields, this is best for caching and performance

Comment: You need to remove the hash tag from the array key `'#test' => [` or it will not render. Elements prefixed with the hashtag are meta data and are not rendered. Elements without the hashtag are rendered.

Comment: @Jaypan, see the question, `test` is a variable of a custom template: `['#theme' => 'custom_template', '#test' => [...]]`

Answer (score 4):

I believe you should use:

```
'#test' => check_markup($node->get('body')->value, $node->get('body')->format);
```

At which point the data will be safely escaped, and therefore this is safe:

```
{{ test.body.value|raw }}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am surprised that nothing in D8 Core uses the `->safe_value`, but [reading this](https://www.drupal.org/node/1052892#comment-4781162) made me feel good about it.

Comment: I thought `->safe_value` worked, but it's actually not printing anything.

Comment: Is safe_value empty, or is the twig value just not printing it?

Comment: `kint($node->get('body')->safe_value);` gives me NULL

Comment: What do you get for this: 
`kint($node->get('body')->getValue())`

Comment: I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8btkA.jpg)

Comment: I edited my code to work with that. I thought safe_value existed in D8, but maybe I was just imagining.

Comment: I gave 4k4's answer an upvote, as it looks to be a better way to go about it.

Comment: If it helps anyone, I was using check_markup to render a field containing a token that outputs a webform, and it wasn't attaching the JS libraries. It was only when I switched to 4k4's approach that it started working. Lost a morning to that one.

Comment: Don't use `safe_value`, but `processed`, i.e. `$node->body->processed`