# How to render content with <p> in twig to create paragraph

Tags: views, theming

Sorry I'm newbie in drupal 8
I want to render my content from database which have `<p>` tags inside and my expectation every `<p>content</p>` will create new paragraph 
My database content was like this:

```
<p>Content 1</p>

<p>Content 2</p>

<p>Content 3<a href="#"></a></p>
```

I was try using `{{ content.value |raw }}` but it was render all content without create new paragraph

I also try using `{{ content.value | raw | nl2br }}` and `{{ content.value | replace({"\n": "<br>"}) | raw }}` but this one create double `<br>` every paragraph so my paragraph become annoying

Is there any solution in twig to render `<p>` tags to create beautifull paragraph?

Thank you

Comment: In Drupal your are allowed to input HTML tags only in a formatted text field. How to safely render such a field see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/238762/how-to-safely-render-node-body-on-a-custom-variable

Answer (score 1):

1) It's bad security practice to use `|raw`. See [How do I get the raw field value in a twig template?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/27710/no-sssweat?tab=answers&sort=votes) for proper/safe way to do it.

2) I am confident that  `{{ content.field_name }}` or `{{ entity.field_name.value }}` is printing  your `<p>` tags. If you right click and inspect element, you should see them in the HTML. Your issue must be CSS related perhaps the `p { ... }` CSS code have an `inline` or a `float` in them.