# How to prevent Cross Site Scripting when input using "Full HTML" mode of CKEditor

Tags: security

I am using Drupal version 8.3.7 and ckeditor 4.11.3.
I create a basic page contains some scripts as following:
[image: Page creation]

In the detail page, I can see that the script in `onmouseover="alert('222222')"` is executed when I move my mouse over the "click" text.

[image: Page detail]

Hacker can easily add a malicious script by this way. How can we avoid this ?

Issue is not only for "Full HTML" mode, but also other modes if we configure a proxy between browser and server to change the encoded value to the raw value.

For example, if we select the "Unfiltered HTML" mode and we input `<a href="#" onmouseover="alert('111111')">click</a>` to the body field. When we save the page, the body value will be sent with a POST request that it is HTML encoded: `&lt;a href=&quot;#&quot; onmouseover=&quot;alert(&#39;111111&#39;)&quot;&gt;click&lt;/a&gt;`. But in the proxy above, we configure to change the encoded value to the raw value. Then the raw value `<a href="#" onmouseover="alert('111111')">click</a>` is saved into DB which will cause the same issue with "Full HTML" mode.

A solution that we can encode the output in theme preprocessing hook. But it seems require us to add a lot of codes because our system may have many entity types and fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the documentation:

> Finally, it should be obvious that the Full HTML input format, which
>   does not use the HTML Filter, is insecure and should be offered only
>   to those users who can be trusted not to ruin your site. Most sites
>   will be better off deleting this input format.

https://www.drupal.org/node/213156

---

"A solution that we can encode the output in theme preprocessing hook. But it seems require us to add a lot of codes because our system may have many entity types and fields."

Don't do this in preprocessing. You can configure your own safe text format containing as many text filters as you want. If the built in text filters don't provide the security you need then add a custom filter.

---

Core ships with Full HTML so that site owners are able to create basic pages in CKEditor using almost all HTML features, which they can do anyway when they have access to the template files.

Comment: It’s weird that core ships with Full HTML, but then the docs like that say to delete it.

Comment: @4k4, I think Drupal core should have filters or input formats that prevent malicious scripts as example I gave in the question ? This is a very common issue, I think.

Comment: Out of the box this is safe, the Full HTML text format is restricted to the Administrator role.

Comment: How can I apply HTML Filter for my html formated field when I customize the display using twig template?

Comment: I don't understand how this is connected to Twig. In a standard install authenticated users can only use Basic HTML and anonymous Restricted HTML. Both text formats include the HTML Filter, with more (for authenticated) or less (for anonymous) allowed HTML Tags..

Comment: An authenticated user can add Full HTML text if he configures a proxy (i.e: Burp proxy) on his browser to change the data sent to server even if he does not see the Full HTML option on the GUI. So we need to filter on the output to avoid xss attack.

Comment: Drupal does apply text format filters on output. A user can add whatever they want to a text field, and Drupal will strip out invalid HTML tags according to the settings of the HTML Filter settings when rendering that field's content.

Comment: You have to output the content applying the text format stored in the database along with the text value, which Drupal does automatically if you use the field formatter of the text field. Are you sure that when you output the database content correctly there is a security issue?

Comment: See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/238762/how-to-safely-render-node-body-on-a-custom-variable

Comment: Thanks @4k4, the issue in [https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/238762/how-to-safely-render-node-body-on-a-custom-variable](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/238762/how-to-safely-render-node-body-on-a-custom-variable) is exactly what I am facing where I use "raw" filter to render html but it also reveals security hole for xss attack. Beside using twig, I am also using VueJS with v-html attribute to show raw html. Can I use Xss::filter() for this case ?

Comment: For REST APIs in general see the change record: ["processed" property of text fields now available in REST](https://www.drupal.org/node/2930012).

Comment: I think above change is not applicable when I expose api using controllers to return Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse. I use Xss::filter(). It seems work fine.

Comment: This is applicable for all Rest APIs, also custom ones.