# How can I add classes to the rendered "body" field on a content type?

Tags: 8, hooks

Preface: I don't often work with Drupal, so I may not be using the correct terminology or fully understand the stack. Please bear with me, I'll do my best to be as clear as possible.

I want to filter the rendered output of the primary "Body" field on a "Basic Page" (or "Article," any content type really) to add some classes to various elements. This would be the field labeled "Body" at `/node/add/page`. I'd like to achieve this using `DOMDocument` in my `.theme` file, but I'm having trouble figuring out what the correct "hook" is to tie in to.

So ultimately the goal would be a function something like the following (which is partially psuedo code):

```
function my_theme_body_alter(&$content) {
    $DOM = new DOMDocument();

    $DOM->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($content, "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8"), LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

    $anchors = $DOM->getElementsByTagName("a");

    foreach ($anchors as $anchor) {
        $existing_classes = $anchor->getAttribute("class") ? $anchor->getAttribute("class") : "";

        $anchor->setAttribute("class", "button {$existing_classes}");
    }

    $content = $DOM->saveHTML($content);

    return $content;
}
```

To be absolutely clear, I want to modify the output (on the front end) of this field:

[image: example]

What is the name of the hook I'm looking for, or how can I locate it myself?

Comment: Are you trying to add classes to the form widget, or to the rendered output?

Comment: The rendered output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to alter the output of a formatter plugin?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/194688/how-to-alter-the-output-of-a-formatter-plugin)

Comment: @Jaypan it may be enough to get me going, I'll report back later today...

Comment: That's actually an auto-message created by the system. 4x4 outlines the methods to achieve your goal in that post.

Comment: A good way to do this for CKEditor content is to add to allowed tags and allowed classes, where the classes are mapped to html elements and css names. No DOMDocument needed for this. Note that the above code will apply button class to any and all `a` tags found, which may not be the desired outcome.

Comment: @Kevin do you have an example on how that works? Not finding much Googling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> note:I have tested it in my machine and it works 100%

1. the `Hook_preprocess_node` is gonna be executed before the rendering of any node of any content-type, you have to apply your logic here but be sure to apply it only of the body field exist otherwise you'll get an error if some content type doesn't have this field, then inject the updated dom into the node.html.twig template using the $varaibles that has been passed by ref to the current hook:

```php
<?php
/**
* Implements  hook_preprocess_hook
*/
function test_preprocess_node(&$variables){
 // 1. Getting the current node.
 $node = $variables['node'];


 //2. Apply this logic to all nodes that have a body field
 if( $node->hasField('body')){

   //3.Get the body field
    $body = $node->body->value;

    //4.Apply som logic on the body field
     $body = updateBodyDom($body);

   //5.injecting the result into the node template (ex: node.html.twig)
   $variables['body'] =  $body ;
 }

}


function updateBodyDom($body){
 $DOM = new DOMDocument();

 $DOM->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($body, "HTML-ENTITIES", "UTF-8"), LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

 $anchors = $DOM->getElementsByTagName("a");

 foreach ($anchors as $anchor) {
   $existing_classes = $anchor->getAttribute("class") ? $anchor->getAttribute("class") : "";
   $anchor->setAttribute("class", "button {$existing_classes}");

   //kint($anchor-> getAttribute('class')); die();
 }

 $content = $DOM->saveHTML( );
 return   $content;
}
```

2. in your templates folder create node.html.twig, to render the
   injected body :

```php
{{ body }}
```

Comment: You should not use the raw filter if the variable could contain user input, which is clearly the case here. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/filters-modifying-variables-in-twig-templates#raw

Comment: @4K4 so what is the best solution you think,  to render the WYSIWYG field into HTML inside our twig template?

Comment: Use `'#type' => 'processed_text'`, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/238780/47547

Comment: But normally you don't need a code solution. The output of formatted text fields is configured in UI, see the [comment from @Kevin](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/294188/how-can-i-add-classes-to-the-rendered-body-field-on-a-content-type/294192?noredirect=1#comment370605_294188). If core doesn't provide the config option you need then install additional text filters.

Comment: This lead me down the right path, accpeted.