# How to render text including video embed field

Tags: media, files, wysiwyg

I have a formatted text field, and am using the video_embed module to allow users to embed video into that field, using the video_embed_wysiwyg submodule.

I am then trying to render the field in a block, but I simply get the JSON output in the text field:

> {"preview_thumbnail":"/sites/default/files/styles/video_embed_wysiwyg_preview/public/video_thumbnails/A5jNGsBHHUE.jpg?itok=7fW8O9To","video_url":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=********","settings":{"responsive":1,"width":"854","height":"480","autoplay":1},"settings_summary":["Embedded
> Video (Responsive, autoplaying)."]}

Here is my render array:

```
$text=check_markup($node->get('field_html_containing_video_content')->value, $node->get('field_html_containing_video_content')->format);

    $renderArray=[
      'content'=>[
        '#type'=>'inline_template',
        '#template'=>$text
      ]
    ];

    return $renderArray;
```

I've got the video embed filter enabled on the relevant text format, and have tried changing the order of the filters.

Any ideas what i am doing wrong here?

We are using a bootstrap subtheme.

Thanks for any help given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`check_markup()` is not able to handle attached metadata which some text filters need to work properly.

You have to use the render element `processed_text`:

```
$renderArray = [
  'content' => [
    '#type' => 'processed_text',
    '#text' => $node->field_html_containing_video_content->value,
    '#format' => $node->field_html_containing_video_content->format,
  ],
];
```

More info [How to safely render node body on a custom variable?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/238762/how-to-safely-render-node-body-on-a-custom-variable)

Comment: Thanks 4k4 - much aprpeciated (and sorry for the slow answer acceptance and reply)