# Returning custom array in lazy builder callback

Tags: views, blocks, caching

I have to return a custom array from a lazy builder callback and then loop through that array in a Twig template for a custom block. Here is my code so far:

Custom block:

```
public function build() {

return [
  '#theme' => 'custom_theme',
  '#variables' => [
    '#lazy_builder' => [static::class . '::lazyBuilder', []],
    '#create_placeholder' => TRUE,
  ],
];
}
```

The callback

```
  public static function lazyBuilder() {

  //code above
      foreach ($vars as $var) {
        $arr[] = [
          'title' => $var->getTitle(),
          'body' => $var->body->value),
          'summary' => $var->summary->value,
        ];
      }
    }

    sleep(3); // For testing only
    return $arr; 
  }
```

In my twig template

```
{% for var in variables %}
  <div>{{ var.title }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

For each item I want to display its title, body and summary. Everything works fine if I return from the callback an array which has #markup inside, but I need to return my custom array.

If that's not possible it would be also OK if a lazy loaded the whole block not just the content inside it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> I have to return a custom array from a lazy builder callback

You can return multiple `#markup` elements nested in the render array, also other render elements like `#plain_text`, which is more safe to output a title containing user input:

```
  'title' => ['#plain_text' => $var->getTitle()],
```

For the body field you need a more complex render element, see [How to safely render node body on a custom variable?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/238762/how-to-safely-render-node-body-on-a-custom-variable)

---

> and then loop through that array in a Twig template

You can't loop through the array in the theme because you have set-up the variable to be lazy-built. The array doesn't exist at this point, only the placeholder. The array needs to be a proper render array which can be rendered recursively as explained above.

---

> If that's not possible it would be also OK if a lazy loaded the whole
> block not just the content inside it.

Blocks are lazy-built by default and placeholdered when meeting the auto-placeholder conditions. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/render-api/auto-placeholdering