# HTML is being printed in the output

Tags: theming

The output from the below code is printing HTML. How can I make the "p" tags disappear?

> ```
> <p>answer 1</p>
> ```

```
{% block paragraph %}
  <div {{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
    {% block content %}
      <h1>{{ content.field_accordion_title.0}}</h1>
      {% for grid_item in paragraph.field_accordion %}
        <button class="accordion">{{ grid_item.entity.field_accordion_list_item_headin.value }}</button>
        <div class="panel">
        {{ grid_item.entity.field_accordion_list_item_text.value }}
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endblock %}
  </div>
{% endblock paragraph %}
```

Note:  I don't want to trim the HTML tags but actually render them. Perhaps drupal_entity() will help to render the output of {{ grid_item.entity.field_accordion_list_item_text.value }}. How can this be done?

Note: I don't want to trim the HTML tags but actually render them. Perhaps drupal_entity() will help to render the output of {{ grid_item.entity.field_accordion_list_item_text.value }}. How can this be done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to safely render node body on a custom variable?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/238762/how-to-safely-render-node-body-on-a-custom-variable)

Comment: Have you tried `striptags`, for example: `{{content.field_media_image.0|render|striptags|trim}}`

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I don't want to trim the HTML tags but actually render them. Perhaps drupal_entity() will help to render the output of {{ grid_item.entity.field_accordion_list_item_text.value }}. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Try
`{{ grid_item.entity.field_accordion_list_item_text.processed }}` instead of `{{ grid_item.entity.field_accordion_list_item_text.value }}`

i.e. replace `value` with `processed`

Answer (score -1):

I assume the string `<p>answer 1</p>` is escaped and printed but you want to actually render the HTML tags.

In that case `{{ grid_item.entity.field_accordion_list_item_text.value | raw }}` should do the trick, **assuming the variable is safe**. If the value was entered by a user, take a look at this: [How to safely render node body on a custom variable?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/238762/how-to-safely-render-node-body-on-a-custom-variable).