# print description and field value directly in taxonomy-term--drzava.html.twig

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 9

First I disable view for taxonomy-term, so I can use taxonomy-term--drzava.html.twig, where drzava is name of vocabulary.

How to print description and filed value for taxonomy-term directly, without using

```
field--taxonomy-term--description--drzava.html.twig
```

`{{ content.description }} or {{ content.field_flag_code}}`

I have problem to analyze devel output. I try `{{ content.description.value }}` but its do not work.

and for field, I try something like this but its do not work. `{{ content.field_flag_code.0.value }}`

In Devel there is **Definition**, **Render** and **Load**, what from this tri tabs I need to look for twig?

Thanks for the help in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description field is a formatted text field which should be printed as processed text render element:

**taxonomy-term.html.twig**:

```
{{ {
  '#type': 'processed_text',
  '#text': term.description.value,
  '#format': term.description.format,
} }}
```

If you want to get rid of the `<p>` tag you have to configure the field with a a different text format or use `|render|striptags` on a variable stored like in the [linked topic](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/238762/how-to-safely-render-node-body-on-a-custom-variable).

The other field value:

```
{{ term.field_flag_code.0.value }}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. I learn one very nice staf. https://prnt.sc/26ja49b I edit a litle your answer

Comment: About your edit, the other field doesn't seem to be a formatted text field.

Comment: I was plane to use field_flag_code field as css marker. <span class="flag-50 flag-icon flag-icon-en flag-icon-squared "> like flag-icon-{{ term.field_flag_code.0.value }} . I was use the some method and its work. :)

Answer (score 1):

I remembered. I hadn't used drupal for a while, so I forgot.

I use Devel:

```
{{ kint(content.description['#items'].getValue()|first.value) }}
```

and in `taxonomy-term--drzava.html.twig`, I Use

```
{{ content.description['#items'].value }}
```

[image]

This is my output. But I don't understand why its display `<P></P>`

Comment: `<p>` tags are probably being added because the description is passed through an input filter, which adds the tags automatically.  If you want to get rid of them, use `striptags`: https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/striptags.html

Comment: Yes, this is clear in the debug output because the field has a property `format`. The correct way is then to output it as processed_text to apply the output filters of the text format, too. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/238762/how-to-safely-render-node-body-on-a-custom-variable. This link is for a node, in a taxonomy term template use `term`.

Comment: @4k4 This is very nice solution. Where to put '#test' => $term in some preprocess functions or..? I always afraid to write preprocess functions.

Comment: You don't need a preprocess hook because the variable `term` is already available, see the documentation at the top of template. I post a code example as answer.